# Maximum multiple-entry visa for Europe with a UK work permit

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry, south-african-citizens

I have a South Africa passport. What is the maximum multiple-entry visa I can get for Europe with a UK work permit? Does the permit improve my chances of getting a longer travel visa for Europe?

Comment: `Does the permit improve my chances of getting a longer travel visa for Europe`. A bit maybe(depending on the country you are from), but it isn't quantifiable.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum validity of a Schengen visa is 5 years (article 24 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/justice_freedom_security/free_movement_of_persons_asylum_immigration/jl0028_en.htm)). What you get is left at the discretion of the consulate to which you apply but I think a UK work permit does indeed improve your chances of getting a multiple-entry visa valid for a year or more.

Note that you cannot in any case stay more than [90 days in any 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) (and therefore stay for than 3 months at once) with such a visa, even if it is valid for 5 years.

I think Romania, Bulgaria and Croatia have similar regulations. I don't know about Cyprus and other non-Schengen countries.